# IPN payment_status variable

Tags: paypal-ipn

I am using PayPal's IPN service to confirm payment.  My listener is checking the payment_status variable hoping to find "Completed".  I don't want to do anything in my database unless the payment comes back "Completed".  My question is, what if it does not come back with that status?  Will PayPal continue to communicate with my listener until it is complete?  For example, the status could come back as "Processed", which appears to be a step before "Completed".  Below is a link to a document with all of the variables:

https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/ipnguide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

On page 10:

> Because IPN messages can be sent at various stages in a transaction’s progress, make sure 
>   that the transaction’s payment status is “completed” before enabling shipment of 
>   merchandise or allowing the download of digital media.

So yes, I think PayPal will always give you an IPN with `Completed` status.